# align magnific popup to the top of the page

Tags: vertical-alignment, magnific-popup

On a PC my Magnific popup works perfectly. However, on smaller screens the popup displays in the middle of the screen forcing the user to have to scroll down to find displayed image. Is there a way of aligning the image in the popup to the top of the page?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the alignTop config property?

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
    alignTop : true,
    items    : { /*your items here*/ }
    })
```

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#aligntop

Comment: I have the same problem, tried the solution suggested here and it didn't help